# Why does Flex's Matrix Transform Snap Child Back to Top Corner of Parent?

Tags: apache-flex, matrix, transform

I'm having trouble with Matrix Transforms in Flex.

I have a Flex Canvas with nothing but an Image in it, like so.

```
<mx:Canvas>
 <mx:Image id="img" source="/some/Url" />
</mx:Canvas>
```

To this image I am applying zoom/rotation transforms using code like this:

```
private function _rotateAndZoomImage(zoom:Number, angle:Number):void{
 var radians:Number = angle * (Math.PI / 180.0);
 var offsetWidth:Number = ( img.contentWidth/2.0 );
 var offsetHeight:Number = (  img.contentHeight/2.0 );
 var matrix:Matrix = new Matrix();

 matrix.translate(-offsetWidth, -offsetHeight);
 matrix.rotate(radians);
 //Do the zoom
 matrix.scale (zoom/100, zoom/100);
 matrix.translate(+offsetWidth, +offsetHeight);
 img.transform.matrix = matrix;
}
```

This all works. BUT. The image is draggable. The user can move it anywhere inside the canvas that is it's parent.

Once **the image has been moved** and the transform is applied **the image gets "snapped" back** to the original 0,0 (top left of the canvas) location before being transformed and is left there afterwards - not where the user would expect it to be.

After messing about with this for the best part of a day I still can't work out why on earth it's doing this. Anybody?

Edit: Note that the same happens without the two calls to .translate() in the above code. So the following code also snaps the image back to 0,0 of the canvas after it has been moved:

```
private function _rotateAndZoomImage(zoom:Number, angle:Number):void{
 var radians:Number = angle * (Math.PI / 180.0);

 var matrix:Matrix = new Matrix();
 matrix.rotate(radians);
 matrix.scale (zoom/100, zoom/100);
 img.transform.matrix = matrix;
}
```

Jake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution/workaround to this is quite simple. Instead of this:

```
<mx:Canvas>
 <mx:Image id="img" source="/some/Url" mouseDown="img.startDrag()" />
</mx:Canvas>
```

I now have this:

```
<mx:Canvas>
 <mx:Canvas id="inner" mouseDown="inner.startDrag()" clipContent="false">
  <mx:Image id="img" source="/some/Url" />
 </mx:Canvas>
</mx:Canvas>
```

The draggable image no longer lives directly inside the main Canvas. Instead it lives inside a child Canvas. The image is no longer draggable itself. It's the inner Canvas that gets dragged.

Now, when a transformation is applied to the image, it stays put as its parent's 0,0 coords are now where they're supposed to be, as it's where you dragged the canvas to.

Hope this helps somebody and saves them the time I've wasted on this.
Jake

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I fixed it. I overrode the 'move' function in my Image class, called super.move(), and then reset the transform matrix to the value I originally set it to (in this case _affineTransform).

```
    override public function move(x:Number, y:Number):void
    {
        super.move(x,y);
        this.transform.matrix = _affineTransform;
    }
```

Hacky, but watcha gonna do...if someone has a cleaner solution, please let me know!

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but doesn't that cause an infinite loop? If you're saying that applying the transform calls move and you're applying the transform from within the override of the move method?

Comment: Good point, but it doesn't cause an infinite loop. Again, I'm not sure if this is the proper solution, but it works. I think this whole issue is a bug in Flex 4. I didn't have this behavior in Flex 3.

Answer (score 1):

If you look in the source code for the `set x()` override in `mx.core.UIComponent`, you'll see the following line:

```
 _layoutFeatures.layoutX = value
```

Basically, it ignores the default display list `x` value and stores the position elsewhere. The real `x` is probably set later once the full layout has been processed (replacing your translation value). You should probably always use `x`, `y`, `scaleX`, `scaleY`, `rotation` and any other relevant properties. It seems that Adobe doesn't intend for Flex to support the regular display object transform matrix.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for delving that deep. I'm glad I didn't go any further down the road of trying to solve it directly now. Instead I used a workaround, which I'll write about in an answer in a mo. I'd like to mark yours as the answer, as it kind of is, but I think my workaround is the answer in my case as it's what solved the problem. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have to add the x,y values to your translation:

```
private function _rotateAndZoomImage(zoom:Number, angle:Number):void{
 var radians:Number = angle * (Math.PI / 180.0);
 var offsetWidth:Number = ( img.contentWidth/2.0 );
 var offsetHeight:Number = (  img.contentHeight/2.0 );
 var matrix:Matrix = new Matrix();

 matrix.translate(-offsetWidth, -offsetHeight);
 matrix.rotate(radians);
 //Do the zoom
 matrix.scale (zoom/100, zoom/100);
 matrix.translate(img.x + offsetWidth, img.y + offsetHeight);
 img.transform.matrix = matrix;
}
```

Comment: Hmmm. That just sends the image shooting off the side of the canvas as you zoom in.

Comment: Further to that - I noticed that if I removed the .translate() calls from before and after the scale/rotate calls it still snaps back to 0,0 so I'm not sure the translations are to blame.

Comment: I'm having this same problem too. You're using flex 4 right? I believe the problem is that UIComponent.move(x,y) is being called after you do the transformation, and that resets the x,y coordinates, along with the transform matrix's tx and ty variables. Not sure what the fix is yet.

Comment: @hisham - good to know I've not alone. I've since "fixed" this by adding the Image inside a second "inner" Canvas. The image no longer gets dragged, but the inner canvas does. Any transformations to the image are now relative to the 0,0 of the inner canvas, which is what we moved, so is always in the right place. I'm still interested in a cleaner approach though...

Comment: @jake, interesting I might try that. I found another solution, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

try setting this.

```
matrix.tx
matrix.ty
```

Comment: Isn't that just the same as calling the .translate() method?

Comment: What are you suggesting I set the values to?

Comment: the position of where you want the image